# Using signalr with sveltekit

Tags: signalr, sveltekit

I'm trying to use signalr with sveltekit. The following line throws an error:

```
const hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/api/notifications").build();
```

I'm sure that /api/notifications endpoint works.
The error message is: Cannot resolve '/api/notifications'. The related code is in SignalR's HttpConnection.js module:

```
_resolveUrl(url) {
    // startsWith is not supported in IE
    if (url.lastIndexOf("https://", 0) === 0 || url.lastIndexOf("http://", 0) === 0) {
        return url;
    }
    if (!Utils_1.Platform.isBrowser) {
        throw new Error(`Cannot resolve '${url}'.`);
    }
    ...
}
```

As expected if I pass full path of "https://localhost:5000/api/notifications", then the error goes away. But relative path does throw the above error.Then I looked into SignalR's Utils.js:

```
class Platform {
    // react-native has a window but no document so we should check both
    static get isBrowser() {
        return !Platform.isNode && typeof window === "object" && typeof window.document === "object";
    }
    ...
}
```

Somehow, isBrowser returns false, resulting in the error.

Can someone help with the issue?

Comment: The following may help: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/3365

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the module which contained the above code in question was imported in layout.ts, and it was executed in node context. So, I factored out the code to avoid importing it in layout.ts. Yet, importing it in +layout.svelte is okay, because in this case hub connection build will be executed in browser context.